# Restar 2 fechas donde una esta guardada como texto

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Deseo obterner la suma total de los dias apartir de la fecha de periodo 25-06-2018.
Mi problema es que la fecha de periodo no puedo modificar y la agrega un 3ro apartir de un formulario y el formato es :

```
Tabla periodo 
id periodo1                   id
1  del 25 de Junio del 2018   varchar(50)

Tabla asistencias
id asistio2                   id
1  26-06-2018                 date
2  27-06-2018
3  28-06-2018
4  29-06-2018
```

mis consultas en php son:

```
$periodo = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT TOP 1 periodo1 FROM periodo ORDER BY idp DESC");
 if($a=sqlsrv_fetch_array($periodo)) {
   $ultimoPeriodo=$a['periodo1'];
} 

$asist=sqlsrv_query($conn, 
"SELECT asistio2 FROM asistencias WHERE asistio2 > $ultimoPeriodo");
if($d=sqlsrv_fetch_array($asist)){
   $asist_suma+=date_format ($d['asistio2'], 'd-m-Y');
}
```

como no puedo trabajar restando `text` a `date` me gustaria saber que metodo podria usar

Answer (score 1):

prueba con esto!

```js
<?php
// Delimiters may be slash, dot, or hyphen
$date = "26-06-2018 ";
list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);
echo "Month: $month; Day: $day; Year: $year<br />\n";
?>
```